# Can a migrated question be, uh, repatriated?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I think the question  » https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25954/set-indesign-pdf-export-resolution-for-vector-graphics?noredirect=1 « was migrated to Superuser too early  as it is, at the core, about a basic issue for anyone who sets out to export press-ready PDFs from InDesign. The OP ill-formulated the question based on technical misconceptions, so it's not making much sense at Superuser's either. Instead, it should stay here and be answered properly (which I tried, but could only do through commenting as the question was put on hold) and maybe be edited a bit.

Comment: Questions **can** be repatriated, but odd things happen to any answers attached (rep [tends not to transfer well](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3974/what-happens-when-questions-are-migrated-twice) between sites). In this case, there aren't any answers yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's a weird case, but it's probably best to leave it as is. Requesting a question to be migrated *from* another site typically requires that the question is closed as off-topic at the site where the question resides.

We try and diminish the overlap between Super User and Graphic Design, but there will certainly be some questions that are within the scope of both sites. Since this question appears to be on-topic as Super User, a migration reversal would probably be frowned upon.

Comment: Completely agree, also worth mentioning that when a question is closed as Off-Topic > Tech Support (without migration), a message is displayed to the user that points them to Super User. So, ideally, the OP can go there and check if there's an existing question *before* an automatic migration.